# Lowercase of Unicode character

Tags: c++, unicode, wchar-t, latin

I am working on a `C++` project that need to get data from `unicode text`.
I have a problem that I can't lower some `unicode character`.
I use `wchar_t` to store unicode character which read from a unicode file. After that, I use `_wcslwr` to lower a `wchar_t` string. There are many case still not lower such as:

```
Đ Â Ă Ê Ô Ơ Ư Ấ Ắ Ế Ố Ớ Ứ Ầ Ằ Ề Ồ Ờ Ừ Ậ Ặ Ệ Ộ Ợ Ự
```

which lower case is:

```
đ â ă ê ô ơ ư ấ ắ ế ố ớ ứ ầ ằ ề ồ ờ ừ ậ ặ ệ ộ ợ ự
```

I have try `tolower` and it is still not working.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow!!

Comment: The standard library is incapable of doing this correctly, you need a decent library.  Also dealing with the trickier corner cases, like the lower-case of `ß` is `ss`, from one char to two.  The ICU library is pretty popular in C++ land.

Comment: if the number of characters that you need to convert to lower is small, you can define yout own mapping arrayinstead of using libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call only `tolower`, it will call `std::tolower` from header `clocale` which will call the `tolower` for ansi character only.

The correct signature should be:

```
template< class charT >
charT tolower( charT ch, const locale& loc );
```

Here below is 2 versions which works well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cwctype>
#include <clocale>
#include <algorithm>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    std::wstring data = L"Đ Â Ă Ê Ô Ơ Ư Ấ Ắ Ế Ố Ớ Ứ Ầ Ằ Ề Ồ Ờ Ừ Ậ Ặ Ệ Ộ Ợ Ự";
    std::wcout << data << std::endl;

    // C std::towlower
    for(auto c: data)
    {
        std::wcout << static_cast<wchar_t>(std::towlower(c));
    }
    std::wcout << std::endl;

    // C++ std::tolower(charT, std::locale)
    std::locale loc("");
    for(auto c: data)
    {
        // This is recommended
        std::wcout << std::tolower(c, loc);
    }
    std::wcout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Reference:**

- [`towlower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/towlower)
- [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower)

Comment: This really help me. Thank you very much.