# Is there a way to compare to string pointers ignoring their case?

Tags: c

I want to compare to string pointers while ignoring their case. I cant think of any C function that can do that.

For example:

```
ToMMy == tommy == TOMMY == tOMmy etc.....
```

Does anyone know how this can be done in C?

Comment: Take a look at [strcasecmp](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r10/topic/com.ibm.zos.r10.bpxbd00/rsrccm.htm) in string.h

Comment: Do you mean the string values themselves or the identifiers in C?

Comment: Suggest you do a Stackoverflow and/or web search before asking questions in the future. Many answers already. For example: [Case Insensitive String comp in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820810/case-insensitive-string-comp-in-c)

Comment: Interested in a true/false compare or an order compare like the result of `strcmp()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is OK to support only single-byte English alphabets to ignore cases, just convert each characters to lower case (or upper case) and compare.

```
#include <ctype.h>

int cmp(const char *a, const char *b) {
    while (*a || *b) {
        int c1 = tolower((unsigned char)*a++);
        int c2 = tolower((unsigned char)*b++);
        if (c1 != c2) return c1 > c2 ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use a quick bit-shift as well and eliminate the `ctype.h` dependency. To convert to lower and compare: `int c1 = (unsigned)*a++ | (1 << 5);` or to upper `(unsigned)*a++ & ~(1 << 5);` It's not any better than `tolower`, but emphasizes the 6th-bit as the lower-case bit in 7-bit ASCII.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In my opinion, that would be worse than `tolower` because it harms readability. Using `tolower` makes the intention more clear.

Comment: I disagree, that is what *comments* are for. e.g. `/* convert to lowercase & compare */`. Without any comments, much of what is done in C isn't immediately apparent. This would certainly be an instance where comment would be called for. There is nothing wrong with `tolower` if you are not doing a huge number of conversions, but if you are, using the case bit can help optimize the routine.

Answer (score 1):

`strcasecmp()` is not a standard C function, but it is on most compilers.

Write your own:

```
int strnocasecmp(char const *a, char const *b)
{
    for (;; a++, b++) {
        int d = tolower((unsigned char)*a) - tolower((unsigned char)*b);
        if (d != 0 || !*a)
            return d;
    }
}
```

Don't forget the `#include <ctype.h>` library for `tolower()`.

Comment: This program may invoke undefined behavior for passing out-of-range value to `tolower()` if `char` is signed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `strcasecmp` (POSIX) in `string.h`, that's probably your best bet.

```
strcasecmp("TOMMY", "tOMmy") == 0
```

Otherwise, it's not too hard to make your own.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool check_strings(const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    if (strlen(str1) != strlen(str2))
        return false;

    do {
        if (tolower(*str1++) != tolower(*str2++))
            return false;
    } while(*str1 || *str2)

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This program may invoke undefined behavior for passing out-of-range value to `tolower()` if `char` is signed.

Comment: @MikeCAT If you see anything, feel free to edit the code. I just sort of rattled it off although I'm pretty sure it works (I obviously didn't work on this too hard).