# Getting rid of || or's in C programming

Tags: c

I'm using `||` so that if the user types in a `Y` or `y` it equals the same. Example: `(option=='y' || option =='Y')` I know there's a single function to get rid of this so that the user types in `Y` or `y` it equals the same.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: From this mess I can assume you are talking about `tolower()/toupper()`...

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820810/case-insensitive-string-comp-in-c for case insensitive string comparison in C

Comment: @tmpearce the dtr function might not work if it's just a char and not a null-terminated char array.

Comment: ASCII/EBCDIC bit hack: `if (option | ('A' ^ 'a') == 'y' | 'Y') ...` for A to Z

Comment: @chux nice hack! But the bitwise `|` expressions need parentheses, due the `==` having higher precedence.

Comment: There is a shorter bithack: `if ((option | ' ') == 'y') ..`

Comment: @Eugene Sh. `if ((option | ' ') == 'y')` works well in ASCII, not EBCDIC.  I was aiming for the idea `'A' ^ 'a'` will isolated the constant bit pattern that differs `'a'` from `'A'` for any sane coding that will ever occur.

Comment: Vote to reopen as [purported dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820810/case-insensitive-string-comp-in-c) was about string case-insensitive compare and this in about a single `char` case insensitive compare.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use `tolower((unsigned char)option) == 'y'` as described on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_tolower.htm (you need to add `#include <ctype.h>`).

Or use a switch statement with fallthrou cases for 'Y' and 'y'.

I suppose if you often have `(option=='y' || option =='Y')` I suppose the best way is to put it into a separate function in your favourite way and call the function ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `option` is of type `char`, you can replace

```
if (option == 'y' || option == 'Y')
```

by

```
if (tolower((unsigned char)option) == 'y')
```

The cast to `unsigned char` is necessary. `tolower` takes an argument of type `int` whose value must be either within the range of `unsigned char` or equal to `EOF` (which is typically `-1`).  If plain `char` happens to be signed (which is common) and if the value of `option` happens to be negative (which could happen if the input is unusual), then `tolower(option)` would have undefined behavior.

(Yes, the need for a cast is annoying and counterintuitive. Yes, `tolower()` *should* accept any argument within the range of `char`. Yes, you still have to deal with it.)

Other possibilities:

```
option = tolower((unsigned char)option);
if (option == 'y') ...
```

or

```
switch (option) {
    case 'y': case 'Y': ...
    ...
}
```

The `switch` solution still tests against both `'y'` and `'Y'`, but it's less verbose; you don't have to mention `option` more than once. And of course you can also `switch` on `tolower((unsigned char)option)`.

Answer (score 1):

1. A fast, albeit memory wasteful approach, is to use a look-up table:

   ```
   #include <limits.h>
   #include <stdbool.h>

   // Initialize all values to false, except for two.
   // Note 'y', 'Y' have positive values in all encodings.
   static const bool IsYory[UCHAR_MAX + 1u] = {
       ['y'] = 1,
       ['Y'] = 1,
       };

   char option = foo();
   if (IsYory[(unsigned char) option]) {
     bar();
   }
   ```
2. A **branch-less** method

   ```
   if (((option - 'y')*(option - 'Y')) == 0) {
   ```
3. If the two letters differ only by 1 bit, like `'y'` and `'Y'` do with ASCII and even EBCDIC encoding,

   ```
   if ((option | ('y' ^ 'Y')) == ('y' | 'Y'))  {
   ```
4. Best to simply use `toupper()`.  Prefer `toupper()` over `tolower()` for more character sets, beyond `'A-Z,a-z'` collapse to upper characters better than to lower. For `A-Z`, it makes no difference.

   ```
   if (toupper(option) == `Y`)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Make all that the user inputs either lowercase or uppercase using the tolower() or toupper() functions, so you won't have a problem.
More info:[Description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/)