# How can I turn 'cin' to lowercase with this code?

Tags: c++, string, game-development

I'm making a text game, and want my options to have a common definer. Which works. But I want `std::cin >> choice;` to always be lowercase, so that an uppercase misspelling doesn't matter for the player. I can't find any answers.

#### *.cpp* file:

```
std::cout << std::endl << "Choice: ";
std::cin >> choice;

if (dLookAround)
{
    std::cout << "ede" << std::endl; // Just a test
}
```

#### Header file:

```
private:
std::string choice;

#define dLookAround \
    (choice == "Look around"\
    || choice == "What do i see?"\
    || choice == "What do i see"\
    || choice == "Explore"\
    || choice == "Scout")
```

In this state, the code works. But I want `cin` to read choice in lowercase, so that I don't need to write every single word with uppercase and lowercase in the `#define` all the time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert std::string to lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply transform the `choice` to lowercase with [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) from `<algorithm>` header and [std::tolower](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) from `<cctype>` header; and. then test it.

For example:

```
std::transform( choice.begin(), choice.end(), choice.begin(),
                []( auto c ){ return std::tolower( c ); } );
```

BTW, you should pass the `choice` to `dLookAround` to make it more readable in the `if` statement like this:

```
if ( dLookAround( choice ) ) { /* ... */ }
```

Or with better naming convetions like `isSelected` and `choice`:

```
if ( isSelected( choice ) ) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: It's easier without including <cctype>, by using `tolower` from the global namespace: `std::transform(choice.begin(), choice.end(), choice.begin(), ::tolower);`

Comment: @RHertel: Yes. That could be an alternative too. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I am such a fool ahaha! The transform didnt work earlier because i defined choice with uppercase letters, so making cin lower letter didnt work because it made the cin to lowercase while choise was uppercase. I switched all the definers to lowercase, and if cin has uppecase, they get transformed to lowercse. So it works now, thanks! :D

Comment: Note that tolower works great on, say, ASCII, but not so good on arbitrary UTF-8 sequences.  `"СЧАСТЬЕ "` will not get converted to `"счастье"`.  If ASCII is all you need for your use case, you're golden!  But if you have to support Unicode, it becomes a bit more of a chore.

Comment: @RHertel code is technically incorrect, as the argument to `::tolower` should be a value in the range of `unsigned char` ; it causes undefined behaviour to pass plain chars with negative values to it .

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use a case-insensitive comparison, like `strcmpi()` or equivalent, instead of converting the input, eg:

```cpp
#define dLookAround ( \
    (strcmpi(choice.c_str(), "Look around") == 0) || \
    (strcmpi(choice.c_str(), "What do i see?") == 0) || \
    (strcmpi(choice.c_str(), "What do i see") == 0) || \
    (strcmpi(choice.c_str(), "Explore") == 0) || \
    (strcmpi(choice.c_str(), "Scout") == 0) \
    )
```

Comment: `strcmpi()` is not a standard C function. If it doesn't exist in your library, you can use my `strncmpci()` function I manually wrote here instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820810/case-insensitive-string-comp-in-c/55293507#55293507