# C - String comparisons, lowercase

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, char

Is there a function in C to compare strings that is not case sensitive. Or do I first have to convert character by character to lowercase and then compare?

Comment: `stricmp` is not technically an official standard function, but it is available in most major standard libraries.  It means **STR**ing **I**nsensitive **C**o**MP**arison.

Comment: Ths function is `strcasecmp()`

Comment: It's a POSIX function, but should be available everywhere you care about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case Insensitive String comp in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820810/case-insensitive-string-comp-in-c)