# Implicit declaration of function ‘str[n]casecmp’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

Tags: c, gcc, c99

I am compiling a C library, using [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99). I am including *string.h* to my translation unit (and I can navigate to the definitions of the str?casecmp functions in my [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) IDE.

The source looks something like this:

```
#include <string.h>

int foo(char* c1, char* c2) {
   return strcasecmp(c1, c2);
}


int foobar(char* c1, char* c2, int n) {
   return strncasecmp(c1, c2, n);
}
```

However, when I attempt to compile, I get the error shown in the title.

I am using GCC version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5).

This is what my gcc command looks like:

```
gcc -c -g -Werror -DE4C_THREADSAFE -DLINUX_BUILD -I../include -I../genutils -std=c99 -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/btypes.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/btypes.o btypes.c
```

What is causing this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: How about including the complete error as well?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These functions are declared in `strings.h`, not `string.h`.

Comment: That is strange ... they are declared in `/usr/include/string.h` on my system (Ubuntu 12.0.4)

Comment: But they are hidden under `#ifdef __USE_BSD` macro. man page says one should include `strings.h`

Comment: Yes, thanks, I just spotted that they are curently #def'ed out (first thing I should have checked really). However, according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291149/difference-between-string-h-and-strings-h,  strings.h is largely deprecated (opposite of what you say) - can you elaborate?.

Comment: I'm not really sure. Both POSIX and man pages definitely suggest using `strings.h`. So I'd stick to them for now.

Comment: Also, you may take a look at this discussion: http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/VBuN9LReKLUd3PAUqGT0

Answer (score 1):

Include the header *strings.h* instead of *string.h*.