# What is this strings.h header in C?

Tags: c, string.h

I was reading about string functions in the book C Primer Plus 6th edition by Stephan Prata chapter 14. It says that

> Some pre-ANSI systems use strings.h instead, and others might lack a
>   string header file entirely.

So, I thought that It shouldn't work if I compile following program on any modern C compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>                // note here strings.h not string.h
void fit(char *c,unsigned u);
int main(void)
{
    char msg[]="Things should be as simple as possible," " but not simpler.";
    puts(msg);
    fit(msg,38);
    puts(msg);
    puts("Let's look at some more of the string.");
    puts(msg + 39);
    return 0;
}
void fit(char *c,unsigned u)
{
    if(strlen(c)>u)
        c[u]='\0';
}
```

I tried it on orwell Dev C++ IDE & Codeblocks 13.12 & it compiles and runs fine. Why I am not getting error?

What is the difference between string.h and strings.h?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291149/difference-between-string-h-and-strings-h](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291149/difference-between-string-h-and-strings-h)